# Find the area of the closed region bounded above by the graph

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

Having some issues understanding this problem. I'm not quite sure what I need to do when it's a closed region. I've gone ahead and taken the intergral of f(x) = 2-x^2 and g(x) = -2

then I use the intervals of -2 and 2, and then take F(X) - G(X) as F(X) is above. My result is a negative number, which doesn't make any sense. Any idea what i'm doing wrong?? I can post my work too, if that helps. Thank you!!

Comment: First, check for sign errors. If that doesn't fix it, post your work.

Comment: Hint: Shift the whole graph up so that $f(x) = 4-x^2$ and $g(x) = 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your integral should be: $$ \int_{-2}^2 \big(f(x) - g(x)\big) \, dx$$

It sounds like that's what you were describing so perhaps there is a sign error somewhere.  Since $f(x) = 2-x^2$ and $g(x) = -2$, then $$f(x) - g(x) = 2-x^2 -(-2) = 2- x^2 + 2 = 4 - x^2.$$

So then the area is given by $$ \int_{-2}^2 (4-x^2) \, dx. $$

Comment: I was taking f(x) and g(x) separately, so either that's the problem, or I was messing a sign up as you mentioned. I'll try it with what you gave above. thanks!

Comment: @beatles1235, integrating $f$ and $g$ separately will still work, if you meant $\displaystyle \int_{-2}^2 f(x) \, dx - \int_{-2}^2 g(x) \, dx$.  Without seeing anything else my guess is you may have accidentally said $f(x) - g(x) = 2-x^2 - 2 = -x^2$.